# Coming back to first viewController and starting a function of firstVIewController from his child viewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I am running from a WebView a plugin (myPluginj)that start ViewControllerA. From that viewControllerA I am moving to viewControllerB and then to viewControllerC.

Now I try by selectin something (in a tableView) in viewControlerC to come back to start position (the place from ViewController1 was defined) and start a function myFUNC there that make `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`

when I am first startting the ViewControllerA i am using:

```
ViewControllerA *ts = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName: @"tss" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *myController = [[UINavigation alloc] initWithRootViewCOntroller:ts];
appDelegate.viewController presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

How should i come back from viewControllerC...I tried `popViewControllerAnimated` but it's only comes back to one controller back.

Comment: Have you tried `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`?

Comment: Yes I tried, and I am coming back one viewController back. but not to the start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to come to ViewControllerA, if so, try dismissModelViewController as

viewControllerA |^  viewControllerB -> viewControllerC

viewControllerA **PresentModelView** viewControllerB **Push** viewControllerC

So returning **back from viewControllerC to viewControllerA**

you can directly **dismiss ModelView viewControllerC** |v viewControllerA

Then it will release navigation controller instance, and so all the view controller in stack viewControllerB and viewControllerC will be released.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Back Root View Controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to go back particular view. You can set pop value of stack.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```